# c++ reading several arrays from several file

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I have several text files, file_1.dat file_2.dat ..... . Each of them contains three columns like this

```
x | y | z
1   2   3
5   8   9
4   3   1
.....
```

I want to define three arrays X[],Y[],Z[], where X[] records the numbers in the first column of all files, Y[] records the numbers in the second column of all files and Z[] saves the third column of all files. So the code should have a loop over the number of files. Also the code should ignore the first row(which is the header of data files). What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just iterate over all of your files and append all the coords from the files to one buffer of vectors..

Here is really simple (**pseudo**) code:

```
struct vec3 {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    vec3(int a, int b, int c) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        z = c;
    }
}

vec3 parseVec3Line(const char* str) {
    // do your real implementation for parsing each line here
    return vec3(str[0], str[2], str[4]);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<vec3> data;

    // iterate over all files you want to read from
    for(const auto& it : files) {
        int fd = open(it); // open the file
        while(!EOF) { // read all lines
            read_line(buffer, fd); // copy each line from file to temp buffer
            data.push_back(parseVec3Line(buffer)); // append the parsed data
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

I suggest you to take a look at [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html) to parse the file.
If you know there will be spaces used as separators between some numbers, you can simply do:

```
bool parseVec3Line(const char* str, vec3& vec) {
    // this regular expression will separate the input str into 4 groups..
    // str(0) contains the input str
    // str(1) contains x coord
    // str(2) contains y coord
    // str(3) contains z coord
    static std::regex regx("^([0-9]+)[ ]+([0-9]+)[ ]+([0-9]+)$");
    std::smatch match;

    if(std::regex_search(str, match, regx) && match.size() != 4)
        return false;

    vec.x = str2int(match.str(1));
    vec.y = str2int(match.str(2));
    vec.z = str2int(match.str(3));
    return true;
}
```

And inside the loop you can do something like:

```
while(!EOF) {
    read_line(buffer, fd);
    vec3 vec;
    if(!parseVec3Line(buffer, vec))
        continue;
    data.push_back(vec);
}
```

Comment: thanks! How to ignore the first row which is x | y | z?

Comment: You can simply use the regular expressions for that. You pass each row to the regex_search and if it matches the regex, you will append the values, if it, however, does not match, you can simply ignore that line.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that append the content of one file to your arrays.
Call this function in a loop that iterates over all the files.

Comment: more specific please!